# react-router upgrading conflict withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

I've seen an upgrade guide [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md) how to use `withRouter` but I have a problem implementing it on my project. It's having problem with my `connect`. When I have my `connect` above `withRouter`, `router` exists on props but not my states, and when I have `connect` below `withRouter`, states exist but not router.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import moment from 'moment';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class ThisComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return ...
  }
});

export default connect(state => ({ oneState: state.oneState, twoState: state.twoState }))(ThisComponent)
export default withRouter(ThisComponent)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you have 3 "export default" when you are supposed to have only one per file.

Your component should look like this

```
import React from 'react';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import moment from 'moment';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ThisComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return ...
  }
});

ThisComponent = connect(state => ({ oneState: state.oneState, twoState: state.twoState }))(ThisComponent)
export default withRouter(ThisComponent)
```

Comment: Oh really!? Ehehe. But ever since I have had two which is `export default class ThisComponent extends React.Component` and `export default connect...`.

Comment: you can export them individually but you should have only one default. Didn't it work?

Comment: Yes it did work. So I've been implementing all my components incorrectly as well. Haha! When I have `connect` without `withRouter`, should the `export default` be on `connect` or still on `.. React.Component`?

Comment: it should be on connect :-P

Comment: So really just one export default. Got it! Thanks so much for that additional lesson.