# click button to route to next page

Tags: reactjs, button, routes

I want to click a button and i navigate to the next page belwo is my button:

```
<RaisedButton label="Sign In"
           style={style}
           labelColor="#fff"
           onClick={this.navigateToHome}
           backgroundColor="#20B2AA" />
```

and this is how i set the onClick Method to route to the next page but it's not working :

```
 navigateToHome = () => {
    <Router>
      <Route  path={"/HomePage"} component={HomeActivity}/>
    </Router>
  };
```

**My full class:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {Card,CardHeader,CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import {Router,Route} from 'react-router'
import {HomeActivity} from './HomeActivity'

const style = {
  margin: 12,
};
export class LoginCardView extends React.Component{


  navigateToHome = () => {
    <Router>
      <Route  path={"/HomePage"} component={HomeActivity}/>
    </Router>
  };

  render()
  {
  return(
    <center>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Card  className="CardLogin" >

  <CardText>
    <div >
     <h4 className="TextLoginCenter"> Sign In</h4>

      <tr>
        <td> <TextField
      hintText="Enter Username"
    /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> <TextField
      hintText="Enter Password"
       type="password"
    /> </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>  <RaisedButton label="Sign In"
           style={style}
           labelColor="#fff"
           onClick={this.navigateToHome}
           backgroundColor="#20B2AA" />  </td>
      </tr>

    </div>
      </CardText>

    </Card>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
</center>
         );
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of react-router you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `withRouter()` and `this.props.router.push()`.

```
import {Router,Route,withRouter} from 'react-router';


class LoginCardView extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    //...
    this.navigateToHome = this.navigateToHome.bind(this);
    //...
    //...
  }
  ...
  navigateToHome(){
    this.props.router.push("/HomePage");
  };
  //...
  //...
  //...
export default withRouter(LoginCardView)
```

Comment: am getting this error  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
LoginCardView._this.navigateToHome`, when i press the button

Comment: yes i did , but also the class has export

Comment: Am now getting this when i remove export on top and i put only bottom  `./src/App.js
67:30-43 './LoginCardView' does not contain an export named 'LoginCardView'.`

Comment: The version is **"react-router": "^4.2.0"**

Comment: are you using another HOC in this component? something like `connect` or ... ? if yes try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37024305/2357848